# Kotlin - Companion object not allowed in an inner class

Tags: android, kotlin, junit4

I am trying to create a test class with an inner class but I am getting an error "**companion object is not allowed here**". What is supposedly be the problem? Please see my sample code snippet below. And also i am using JUnit4 for this development.

```
    @RunWith(Enclosed::class)    
    class OuterUnitTest{
    
            @RunWith(Parameterized::class)
            inner class Inner1UnitTest {

                @Test
                fun testInner1(){
                    // test code here
                }

                companion object{
                    @JvmStatic
                    @Parameterized.Parameters
                    fun testData() : Any? {
                        return something
                    }
                }
            }
       }
```

Comment: Does `Inner1UnitTest` have to be `inner`? If you remove the keyword, the code will become compilable.

Comment: My original code doesn't have an **inner** keyword, I'm just trying a client suggestion for this one. But I can't find an explanation why a companion object is not allowed.

Comment: This is just a guess, but maybe it is disallowed to avoid confusion. Inner class exists in the context of the outer class, but companion is static, so it can't be placed in such a context. Some people might try to access members of the outer class from inside the companion, because they think it is inner as well.

Comment: Inner classes are designed to be used only alongside with their outer classes. It makes sense that you cannot have a companion object for inner classes, otherwise there would   exist fields and methods that does not rely on outer class.

Comment: This was also my initial idea, due to companion object being a static variable/method. And if I will make a static inner class (aka: nested class) it will not reference to the outer class. Anyways, this issue has been solved after I explained to my client that this will not be feasible. Thanks for your ideas

Answer (score 0):

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqFfg.png)

[no error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6KEz.png)

I had the same issue. It is necessary to move the block with the initialization of constants to the beginning of the class.

this solved my problem this solution worked for me

Comment: This is not the same issue, it wouldn't work for this case because the `companion object` for a `Parameters` declaration must be in the test class it relates to (which makes sense, if you put it at the `Enclosed` level then JUnit would have no way to know which test class these parameters are meant to be used with)

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, you shouldn't use an `inner` class here. I've managed to create `Enclosed` classes with `Parameterized` subclasses in Kotlin and it works fine.

Example of implementation (skeleton):

```
@RunWith(Enclosed::class)
class MyOuterClass {
    @RunWith(Parameterized::class)
    class FirstNestedClass {
        @Parameterized.Parameter(0)
        @JvmField
        var exampleParamOne: Boolean = false

        @Parameterized.Parameter(1)
        @JvmField
        var exampleParamTwo: Boolean = false

        @Parameterized.Parameter(2)
        @JvmField
        var exampleParamThree: Boolean = false

        @Test
        fun exampleTest() {
        }

        companion object {
            @Parameterized.Parameters
            @JvmStatic
            fun parameters(): Array<Array<Any?>?> {
                return Array(8) { i ->
                    val paramOne = i < 4
                    val paramTwo = i % 4 < 2
                    val paramThree = i % 2 == 0
                    arrayOf(paramOne, paramTwo, paramThree)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @RunWith(Parameterized::class)
    class SecondNestedClass {
        @Parameterized.Parameter(0)
        @JvmField
        var paramOne: Boolean = false

        @Parameterized.Parameter(1)
        @JvmField
        var paramTwo: Boolean = false

        @Test
        fun exampleTest() {
        }

        companion object {
            @Parameterized.Parameters
            @JvmStatic
            fun parameters(): Array<Array<Any?>?> {
                return Array(4) { i ->
                    val paramOne = i < 2
                    val paramTwo = i % 2 == 0
                    arrayOf(paramOne, paramTwo)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```